# How do I enable/disable hotspot or tethering mode programmatically on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, wifimanager, android-developer-api

I see many references on Android's website to [local Only Hotspot](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/localonlyhotspot)

However I need to manage the cellular hotspot programmatically from a background service as I can do manually from the pulldown menu.

This used to be done like:

```
method = wifiManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, Boolean.TYPE);
method.invoke(wifiManager, wifiConfiguration, activated);
```

However this feature has been deprecated.

My wireless provider (AT&T) is trying to charge me differently based on what device is connected and how. The network should be agnostic to devices and just transport my packets to their destination. I hope this is not related, but I am worried we our losing control over our devices.

Does Android really not provide simple API calls for managing the hotspot?

Answer (score 2):

Only privileged apps can can enable/disable hotspots in Android. If you happen to be developing such an app (or have a rooted device), you can use the below APIs.

**If using Android Version >= 11**

You can start a hotspot with `TetheringManager#startTethering` code [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/modules/Connectivity/Tethering/common/TetheringLib/src/android/net/TetheringManager.java?q=func:startTethering).

Similarly, there is a `TetheringManager#stopTethering` method with code [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/modules/Connectivity/Tethering/common/TetheringLib/src/android/net/TetheringManager.java?q=func:stopTethering). This will stop a hotspot.

**If using Android Version < 11**

`ConnectivityManager#startTethering` can be used with code details [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-9.0.0_r3/core/java/android/net/ConnectivityManager.java#2261). Likewise, there is a `ConnectivityManager#stopTethering` method with code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-9.0.0_r3/core/java/android/net/ConnectivityManager.java#2298).

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to test out your suggestion and had a quick question. Can I git clone https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject? This is so I don't have to recreate each file in my project, just import. I found a mirror on gitlab but it does not have the tethering code. Thanks again.

Comment: I found this: git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/superproject but it does not get me to the tethering code.

Comment: I get `Service tethering: not found` I am using Android version 9.

Comment: Finally had time to test this and it looks like `startTethering` is a private method indicated by `@hide`. So I get this message `Cannot resolve method 'startTethering' in 'ConnectivityManager'`

Comment: I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.TETHER_PRIVILEGED" />` in AndroidManifest but it installs as a regular app. And I don't have write access to `/etc/permissions`. Does this require me to root my device (Samsung SM-N950U)? That limits the number of people who can use the app but if it's the only way I will do it.

Comment: I have needed this for many different use cases - right now I need it to turn into a hotspot when I get into my car because I run Ubuntu in there (https://github.com/physiii/open-dash) and want it to autoconnect without me having to fiddle with my phone. But even if there wasn't an obvious use case, I want to explore my devices and have complete control to program as I want. Why limit us? For safety? Come on.

Comment: Sadly, and weirdly, the official docs example at https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-softap-tethering#source is gone. 404.

Comment: Which is why answers with sample code are preferred over links.  I feel like I'm Tantalus, reaching for the grapes or the water.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I removed the stale link.

Answer (score 1):

Your app requires the following two privileges (only available to system applications):

- android.permission.TETHER_PRIVILEGED
- android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS

Once you've secured those permissions, though, you can try the following (kotlin):

```
fun startTethering(ctx: Context) {
  val o = ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)
  for (m in o.javaClass.methods) {
    if (m.name.equals("tether")) {
      try {
        m.invoke(o, "eth0") // or whatever you know the iface to be
      } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
      } catch (e: IllegalAccessException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
      } catch (e: InvocationTargetException) {
        val target = e.targetException
        Log.e("tethering", "target: ${target.message}")
        e.printStackTrace()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you want code to untether the iface, use the same code as above, but replace 'tether' with 'untether'.

I have only tested this code against Android 11.  Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Well, it might work for someone maybe with an older device or something, but it didn't work for me.  For me, the logging shows 'Tried to Tether an unknown iface: eth0, ignoring', even though eth0 is very definitely one of the ifaces available on my target device.  Argh.

Answer (score 0):

I am providing another answer in case, for some, the answer above does not work for them (as it did not work for me).

I suspect this will work for most version of Android 11+:

```
fun startTethering(ctx: Context) {
    try {
        val outputDir = ctx.codeCacheDir
        val proxy = ProxyBuilder.forClass(classOnStartTetheringCallback())
            .dexCache(outputDir).handler { proxy, method, args -> {
                when(method.name) {
                    "onTetheringStarted" -> Log.v(TAG, "onTetheringStarted")
                    "onTetheringFailed" -> Log.v(TAG, "onTetheringFailed")
                    else -> { ProxyBuilder.callSuper(proxy, method, args)}
                }
            }}.build()
        val o = ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        for (m in o.javaClass.methods) {
            if (m.name.equals("startTethering")) {
                try {
                    Log.v(TAG, "found, and invoking startTethering method.")
                    m.invoke(o, 5, false, proxy, null)
                } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                } catch (e: IllegalAccessException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                } catch (e: InvocationTargetException) {
                    val target = e.targetException
                    val cause = e.cause
                    Log.e(TAG, "target: ${target.message}")
                    if (cause != null) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "cause: ${cause.message}")
                    }
                    e.printStackTrace()
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "exception thrown: ${e.message}")
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error building proxy: ${e.message}")
        return
    }
}
```

The '5' that you see for 'm.invoke(o, 5, false, proxy, null)' refers to the ethernet... most likely, the enumeration won't be available to your code, if you're having to take this approach.

To stop tethering:

```
fun stopTethering(ctx: Context) {
    val o = ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    for (m in o.javaClass.methods) {
        if (m.name.equals("stopTethering")) {
            try {
                Log.v(TAG, "found, and invoking stopTethering method.")
                m.invoke(o, 5)
            } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            } catch (e: IllegalAccessException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            } catch (e: InvocationTargetException) {
                val target = e.targetException
                val cause = e.cause
                Log.e(TAG, "target: ${target.message}")
                if (cause != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "cause: ${cause.message}")
                }
                e.printStackTrace()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "exception thrown: ${e.message}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Again, the mystery '5' refers to the ethernet.

Extra information you will need to use this:

Your AndroidManifest.xml file requires the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.TETHER_PRIVILEGED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

You will also need the to **import com.android.dx.stock.ProxyBuilder**, adding to your dependencies whatever the latest is from **com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker**.

Even with all of this, it will not work without signing the app before installing it on your device.  You can't just throw this into your app and expect it to work; instead, sign the app, and install it as a system app.  You can likely work with your vendor to figure out how best to sign the app.

However, to install or update it, you'll need to use something like the following:

```
adb root
adb remount
adb shell rm /system/app/yourapp.apk || true
adb push /path/to/yourapp.apk /system/app/
adb shell chmod 644 /system/app/yourapp.apk
adb install /path/to/yourapp.apk || true
adb reboot
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I am providing another answer in case, for some, the answer above does not work for them (as it did not work for me). Works on Android 14.

For my use-case I only had to disable hotspot programmatically.

Your app does not have to be a system app. You just need:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

in the manifest. Then you request it using:

```
val REQUEST_WRITE_SETTINGS = 1

if (!PermissionUtils.hasWriteSettingsPermission(this)) {
    PermissionUtils.requestWriteSettingsPermission(this, REQUEST_WRITE_SETTINGS);
} else {
    // Permission already granted, you can proceed with your task
    Toast.makeText(this, "WRITE_SETTINGS permission already granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Then just use this modified function from the above answer:

```java
fun stopTethering(ctx: Context) {
    val o = ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    for (m in o.javaClass.methods) {
        if (m.name.equals("stopTethering")) {
            try {
                Log.v(TAG, "found, and invoking stopTethering method.")
                for (i in intArrayOf(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)){
                m.invoke(o, i)}
            } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            } catch (e: IllegalAccessException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            } catch (e: InvocationTargetException) {
                val target = e.targetException
                val cause = e.cause
                Log.e(TAG, "target: ${target.message}")
                if (cause != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "cause: ${cause.message}")
                }
                e.printStackTrace()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "exception thrown: ${e.message}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```